# How to get the local date and time from utc

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am confused on how to display the time from a format like:
2014-03-18T10:00:00-0400

This is what is saved on the backend with the utc offset. It displays fine in the calendar.
But, I am trying to display it in a input field and I can't get the format to local date.

```
e.g.
<input type="date" name="start-dt" value="03/18/2014" >
<input type="time" name="start-time" value="22:00" >


moment("2014-03-18T10:00:00-0400").format("HH:SS") returns 10:00
```

How do I get the offset to be considered and convert it back to 2PM local?

Comment: can't you just add the offset from UTC before you format?

Comment: does momentjs do that for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dateUTC = new Date("2014-03-18T10:00:00"); //Will give you a Date Object of 6:00 AM - 400
var offset = dateUTC.getTimezoneOffset(); //positive if left of GMT, negative if right of GMT
var newDate = new Date(dateUTC.getTime() - (offset * 1000 * 60 * (offset > 0 ? -1 : 1))));
alert(d.getHours() + ":" d.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
var d = new Date("2012-05-03T09:40:34.764Z");
alert(d);
```

this will give the local value because "Z" indicates that its UTC and the javascript understands that and gives the local time.

Comment: var d = new Date("2014-03-18T10:00:00-0400") shows "Mar 18 2014 10:00:00 GMT-0400"  So the offset is still there. I just want a utility that gives me the 14:00 on time.